# Lua scripts stored in memory

Tags: lua

I'm facing problem with lua,

Everytime I'm executing a function/command or even define a variable, everything is stored as a string in memory.

And it can be read via programs like Cheat Engine or HxD

For example

```
 x = 'Test'
```

If I search for the string x = '
I will be able to extra the whole command from memory.
Same for functions

```
function Test()
   print(1);
end
```

Searching Test() will allow me to obtain the whole function script.

Here's an example image
http://i40.tinypic.com/6oh281.png

as you can see in the bottom of the Memory Viewer window, theres the whole function information.

Now how could I prevent lua from creating 'extra' copies of the script in memory?
Garbagecollector does not wipe it out.

Any solution or idea to prevent this would be welcomed.

Comment: I believe JIT always does that...

Comment: What do you mean by 'preventing extra copies'? Do you just want to load the script once?

Comment: I can't see the image anyhow. Can you please upload it somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry for delay,
At the bottom right, you can view the Lua function as plain text, so I by Extra copies I meant, avoiding of the script being visible anywhere  in memory as plain text..

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure what you mean but try `luaL_loadbuffer(L,script,strlen(script),”=noname”)`for loading scripts. If you use `luaL_dostring` then the entire script is saved as its own name.

Note also that you can load a script once and run it multiple times, without having to load it again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to load the Lua source of a script at all. Pre-compile the script with `luac -s`. Of course, the Lua bytecode and strings will still be accessible in memory and just as easily found.

#### Update

The output of luac is a script in binary form. Use it just like a Lua script. You can use it with `loadstring`, `loadfile` etc.

Make your test.lua:

```
print("testing")
```

Test:

```
luac -o test.lub -s test.lua
lua test.lua
lua test.lub
```

To see what you are exposing vs the Lua source:

```
luac -l test.lub
```

Comment: The lua scripts are stored on my server (To avoid users from having download each update, since the application is 1 single standalone .exe).

Answer (score 0):

By default lua stores the key(`x`) as string, and value as object on memory, There's not much you can do with it except managing your scripts and storing values inside a block only. Still, This way can be detected by cheat-engines but it's a lot more secure than default.

safe.lua:

```
local protected = {}

protected.x = "Test"

safe = {}

function safe.Get(pass, val)
    if pass == "0x012345" then
         if not protected[val] then return nil end
         return protected[val]
    end
    return nil
end

function safe.Set(pass, val, key)
    if not pass == "0x012345" then return end
    protected[val] = key
end

function safe.Remove(pass, val)
     if not pass == "0x012345" then return end
     if not protected[val] then return end
     protected[val] = nil
 end
```

test.lua:

```
safe.Set("0x012345", "b", {C = "111"})
print(safe.Get("0x012345", "b").C)
```

If you want to use a custom pass for each key, then use this safe.lua:

```
local protected = {}

safe = {}

function safe.Get(pass, val)
    if protected[val] then
         if not protected[val][pass] then return nil end
         return protected[val][pass]
    end
    return nil
end

function safe.Set(pass, val, key)
    protected[val] = {}
    protected[val][pass] = key
end

function safe.Remove(pass, val)
     if not protected[val] then return end
     if not protected[val][pass] then return end
     protected[val][pass] = nil
end
```

and test.lua:

```
safe.Set("tsting", "x", "keey")
print(safe.Get("tsting", "x"))
print(safe.Get("testing", "x"))
```

Comment: Please check the image
I've wrote in Lua Engine function test() print(1) end
And I used a memory browsing tool, and I was able to read the function itself.
And That method to get variables or objects, I'm already using it.
I came up with bit better way ;)